# How to access the MainForm of a Winforms application during debugging

Tags: vb.net, winforms

If I'm stopped at a break-point how do I get to the instance of the start-up form from the Immediate Window?

I've tried:

```
?CType(Application.OpenForms(0),MyForm)
```

<del>But that doesn't seem to work..</del> **Actually the above does work!**

Are there any simpler ways of doing the above?

Comment: What happens when you do that?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel All I seem to get is `Identifier Expected` this is vb.net and I'm not normally a vb.net guy!

Comment: Am also not vb.net guy:) I wonder why it should fail. In c# this will work `(MyForm)Application.OpenForms[0]` in immediate window also

Comment: OK, My mistake; It is actually working.. :| Sorry. I think I was using square brackets! Is there any other ways?

Comment: you could start from a `Sub Main`; create a form reference for MyForm; then start the app with that form as the message pump.

Comment: Why the down-votes and close? this IS a VALID question?

Comment: @Plutonix this is legacy code I'm trying to debug, Cheers.